# Regex smallest capture

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find interfaces that contain specific words in the config 'blocks'. E.g.:

```
!
interface FastEthernet303
 description Customer Access
 switchport access vlan 40
 no ip address
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan343
 description Customer_LAN
 vrf forwarding 1
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.254.0
!
interface Dialer1
 description 1-1-1
 ip flow monitor GO-FLOW input
 ip flow monitor GO-FLOW output
 keepalive 5 3
!
```

I want only the interface Dialer1 to be captured.

If I use the '!\ninterface (.*?)\n(.*).*?\n!' as regex it starts from 
the first interface (matches first !\interface etc) and captures accros interface blocks and I want it only to capture blocks with for example the key words 'flow monitor' in them:

```
interface Dialer1
 description 1-1-1
 ip flow monitor GO-FLOW input
 ip flow monitor GO-FLOW output
 keepalive 5 3
```

I've tried some negative lookup but can't seem to get it right.

Anyone able to help with this please?

The next step would be to extract the interface name but that should be easy once I have the first part.

Many Thanks

Frank

Comment: What language or tool do you use? There are several flavours of `regex` and the syntax depends on the language or tool do you use to match the `regex`.

Comment: Thanks wasn't really concerned about version of regex as any would have helped me, but I'll remember to add next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think you can do this without using lookarounds.  In the pattern below I use `[^!]` to cautiously proceed in the pattern without passing an interface marker `!`.

```
interface[^!]*flow monitor[^!]*
```

This answer strongly relies on `!` serving as a divider between interfaces.  If this not be the case, then my answer is going to have to change.

### Demo